# Milkiness after adding clearing agent (finnings)

Tags: bottling, finings

I have added the clearing agent to my brew...on the 22nd of December. But, just pulled a sample to check numbers before bottling...and its still a little milky.

- Is this normal?
- Will it clear up the longer it stands?
- Does it become clearer  after bottling and carbonation?
- Is this a problem?

The numbers on the hydrometer haven't dropped to 1000 as per the instructions.  But, I was told by a homebrew shop owner that it doesn't matter as long as you get 3 readings the same?

It is a Brigalow homebrew kit. I don't know what the finnings are called, they just what came with the kit.

Comment: What fining?   And what  brew it was?    Also, the part about hydrometer is a separate question and shouls be asked as such.

Comment: Just trying to find out if something is wrong or all on track! So about 5he hydrometer is part of this question....as it tells me where I am in the cycle. Ive never done a brew...so the hydrometer is my guide!

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us what fining agent you are using and what was the recipe of your beer. Without that, all we could do is to blindly guess.

Comment: Ok. I shouldve probably done some more research before I started.

Comment: Dang, they even list it as "7g Sachet Beer Finings (Clearing Agent)"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. First things first, kits are neat, but if [someone](https://www.bigw.com.au/product/brigalow-complete-home-brew-kit/p/WCC100000000008476/) lists their fining agent just as *"7g Sachet Beer Finings (Clearing Agent)"* I urge you not to put that stuff in your beer. Prefer kits without yeast and fining agents and choose them yourself. Or at least use kits that tells you what's in them, exactly. Or just unhopped extract.

Mild milkiness is expected with gelatin, bentonite and isinglass. It comes from two things, the colour of your fining agent, and the fact you needed to stir your batch, lifting up yeast back into suspension. With isinglass it usually took few days to go down. With bentonite a bit more, about a week.

Now what you can do is to try and "cold crash" it.  If it's winter on your hemisphere, simply put fermenter outside. Don't let it freeze, just let it cool. A day or two should do the job. Alternatively, bottle as is, and put bottles in a fridge.  Once yeast and other stuff settles down on the bottom, it tends to stay there.

Comment: Thank you! Ive learned more about brewing beer since I bought this kit than I ever thought possible! One thing is clear......this kit has got some weird ideas! Learned a lot of things Ill do different on my next batch!

Comment: @JacoGroenewald Glad to help :)